# Рассчёт уравнения прямой из луча

Tags: геометрия, шейдеры

У меня есть начальные координаты луча и его направление в виде нормализованного вектора (назовём этот вектор "a"). 
Проблема заключается в том, что мне нужно составить два уравнения плоскости -> нужны ещё два вектора b и с, которые не являются коллинеарными и не коллинеарны вектору a. Вектор с можно получить векторным произведением вектора a на вектор b, но как получить вектор b для меня остаётся загадкой.

P.S.: В данном случае начальные координаты луча являются вершиной геометрической фигуры, а направление луча - нормальный вектор. Можно ли использовать тангент и бинормальный вектора в качестве b и с?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для уравнения плоскости других векторов не нужно - достаточно нормали и точки на плоскости.

В данном случае, видимо, задача состоит в том, чтобы создать произвольный вектор, перпендикулярный данному. Это можно сделать так:

Выберем наибольший по амплитуде компонент вектора, и следующий по амплитуде.
Пусть это будут для примера y и z-компоненты `(Abs(y)>=Abs(z)>=Abs(x))`

Обнулим третий компонент, а эти два поменяем местами, и изменим знак наибольшего. Для данного пример получается

```
N = nx, ny, nz 
P = 0, nz, -ny
```

Скалярное произведение этих векторов нулевое, они перпендикулярны.

```
 N.dot.P = nx * 0 + ny * nz - ny * nz = 0
```

Таким образом, вектор P лежит в плоскости, можно создать ещё один вектор в плоскости, используя векторное произведение `N x P`